# How to implement a message sending system?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a specialized object class that sends messages to its components so that they can change themselves as needed. The object class allows me to mix and match components so that I can have different objects with similar functionality without having a huge inheritance tree. (I think this is called the component pattern.) Here's what I want to do:

```
//MyObject.java
public class MyObject {

    private HashSet<MyComponent> components_;

    void send(Message message) {
        for (MyComponent component : components_) {
            component.receive(message);
        }
    }

    // other unrelated methods and variables...

}

// MyComponent.java
public interface MyComponent {

    public void receive(Message message);

    // other unrelated methods...

}

// RendererComponent.java
public class RendererComponent implements MyComponent {

    public void receive(Message message) {
        if (message.getType() == Message.Type.POSITION_CHANGED) {
            Point positionDifference = message.getInfo();
            redraw(positionDifference);
        } else if (message.getType() == Message.Type.SCORE_CHANGED) {
            Integer score = message.getInfo();
            redraw(score);
        } // else if...
    }

    private void redraw(Point positionDifference) {
        // draws item at new position...
    }

    private void redraw(Integer score) {
        // draws the new score...
    }

    // other unrelated methods and variables..
}
```

I have a lot of components and they receive many different types of messages. How do I write my Message class so that I can get information of different class types from it? Do I need to change the way my component class handles messages?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by `How do I write my Message class so that I can get information of different class types from it?`. Maybe you could provide an example of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @AlexLynch I want my getInfo() method in my Message class to return different information with different class types (as shown in my example of a RendererComponent) so that the information can be processed in different ways.

Comment: I don't suppose your getInfo() could just return an Object? As long as you use getType() to confirm the type of object you're receiving, I don't foresee any type-safety problems - or would it be discouraged regardless for not being very type-safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a specialized object class that sends messages to its components so that they can change themselves as needed.

The normal (and easy) way to do this kind of thing is with Java's internal event publishing mechanisms.  You define a class that represents an event, and an interface that event listeners / consumers must implement with an "event occurred" callback method.  An event producer has a register method for registering an event consumer, and keeps a list of registered consumers.  When the producer wants to send an event, it creates an event object and then calls the "event occurred" callback for all registered consumers.

This approach is used throughout the Java's GUI libraries, and in other places.  It is lightweight and efficient ... and probably a better idea than doing this kind of thing by message passing.

---

A good place to start learning about events is the [Introduction to Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) in the Swing tutorial.

Comment: I considered that, but I got confused about whether I could add an event listener to a class that doesn't fire an event. Can you give a short example of how to implement it with events?

Comment: Also how would I make sure that only the components of the same object got the events sent by another component of that object?

Comment: @Eva - 1) I added a link to the relevant part of the Swing tutorial.  2)  You would arrange that each component object registered an event listener with the container object.  If you needed one component to be able to send events to other components, the container would need to expose a method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a [publish/subscribe (or pub/sub) system](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).  Check out the [`EventBus` implementation in the Guava library](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/package-summary.html).